# An error when building the code from the 'Explain-to-Fix' paper

Tags: build, caffe

I try to rebuild the code for the [E2X](http://arxiv.org/abs/1811.08011) paper.
I prepared the [repository](https://github.com/dmitrii-badretdinov/caffe_ssd-and-e2x-merged) with the manual to reproduce the error.

I've successfully built and ran tests for the clean [caffe/ssd](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) branch.
When building the same branch with the merged [E2X code](https://github.com/gudovskiy/e2x), I get the following error from `make`:

```
detection_evaluate_layer.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void caffe::DetectionEvaluateLayer<Dtype>::Forward_cpu(const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&, const std::vector<caffe::Blob<Dtype>*>&)’:
detection_evaluate_layer.cpp:170:58: error: ‘const value_type’ {aka ‘const class caffe::NormalizedBBox’} has no member named ‘idx’
  170 |           top_data[num_det * EVAL_SHAPE + 9] = bboxes[i].idx();
      |                                                          ^~~
detection_evaluate_layer.cpp:196:60: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<caffe::NormalizedBBox>, caffe::NormalizedBBox>::value_type’ {aka ‘class caffe::NormalizedBBox’} has no member named ‘idx’
  196 |             top_data[num_det * EVAL_SHAPE + 9] = bboxes[i].idx();
      |                                                            ^~~
detection_evaluate_layer.cpp:221:60: error: ‘__gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<caffe::NormalizedBBox>, caffe::NormalizedBBox>::value_type’ {aka ‘class caffe::NormalizedBBox’} has no member named ‘idx’
  221 |             top_data[num_det * EVAL_SHAPE + 9] = bboxes[i].idx();
```

When looking at the [caffe/ssd](https://github.com/weiliu89/caffe/tree/ssd) branch, I noticed that it used `idx`, but never `idx()`.
The error appears in the code introduced by E2X.

Does anyone have an idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add a field in the `src/caffe/proto/caffe.proto` file:

```
    optional int32 idx = 9;
```

Here's the [link](https://github.com/dmitrii-badretdinov/caffe_ssd-and-e2x-merged/commit/ab4dd2a7d7df41a20e6ccf524c85458700c9c781) for the fix.